# PYTHON:I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, indentation

I believe its all about indentation, but I'm not sure how to indent it accurately, please help me.

```
import csv


with open('abbreviations.csv', mode='r') as infile:
   reader = csv.reader(infile)


with open('abbreviations_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
   writer = csv.writer(outfile)

   mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}

   print(len(mydict))
   print(mydict['v'])
   mydict['MIS'] = 'Management Information System'
   print(mydict['TA'])
   mydict['TA'] = 'teaching assistant'
   print(mydict['TA'])
   print(mydict['flower'])
   del mydict['flower']
```

Comment: The input file is open only within the scope of your first `with` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
with open('abbreviations.csv', mode='r') as infile, open(  # you can put two opens after 
          'abbreviations_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:   # one with statement
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}

    print(len(mydict))
    print(mydict['v'])
    mydict['MIS'] = 'Management Information System'
    print(mydict['TA'])
    mydict['TA'] = 'teaching assistant'
    print(mydict['TA'])
    print(mydict['flower'])
    del mydict['flower']

# on this indentation level the files are closed
```

As soon as you leave the indentation of the `with open(...) as f:` the file gets auto-closed.

You can find more infos here:

- [reading-and-writing-files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- [PEP-0343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Comment: I learned more after reading  infos you recommend, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @joa You are never using your `writer` file object for anything - I guess you skipped that part of your code because it is working?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
import csv

with open('abbreviations.csv', mode='r') as infile:
   reader = csv.reader(infile)

   with open('abbreviations_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
       writer = csv.writer(outfile)

       mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}

       print(len(mydict))
       print(mydict['v'])
       mydict['MIS'] = 'Management Information System'
       print(mydict['TA'])
       mydict['TA'] = 'teaching assistant'
       print(mydict['TA'])
       print(mydict['flower'])
       del mydict['flower']
```

When you use with open the file is closed automatically when the loop ends.

Comment: I get it. Thanks a loooot!

Comment: Glad I could help!